# Authenticate to Dropbox in Python

Tags: python, dropbox, url

I am trying to download a file from Dropbox.com programmatically through Python. For this, I need to know the URL from which I am going to download the file. I tried to get this URL through Chrome and Firefox but the URL that I get is

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/200MB.zip?w=AAD3xS6ous6uTypmnsrZE_r7m3gt0A7DN2gYCUqtjmc-3g&dl=1

When I use this URL, I get an error of **HTTP Forbidden**

Please suggest how to get the url so that I can download the file!

Comment: Are you getting the error message via the programme or via FireFox/Chrome?

Comment: @DaveRook: I am getting it via programme.. and it just gives me HTTP 403 forbidden error..

Comment: Probably because the program isn't able to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python-API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core) for dropbox. It's a really good possibility to download files. Also you can do many other things like search etc.

You can also let dropbox create you a valid downloadlink. Click on this symbol behind your files name. Because this file-link is no valid downloadlink for users which aren't logged in. You have to create a link which can be used by someone who isn't logged in.

[image: Dropboxlink]

[How to download a File with Python?](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/)

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful link but in my question, Dropbox is just an example of a website where I am trying to download a file. I am looking for a generic solution say what if I want to download a file from www.justcloud.com?

Comment: Well the problem is, that you haven't the permission to download this file when you aren't logged in in dropbox. You have to click on that link at the right side of the name of your file in dropbox. Because than everyone can download that file. Otherwise only when you are logged in, you can download it. Error 403 says: "It seems you don't belong here! You should probably sign in". So click on the symbol which i've posted you above at your file and than you should be able to download it. [How to download a file](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/).